# Calling a C# function from unmanaged c++ (via a managed wrapper)

Tags: c#, c++, callback, unmanaged, managed

I have C++ source & headers for a set of libraries which I need to call from a C# application.  I've created a managed C++ wrapper around the functions I need and am able to call them from C# marshalling the data backwards and forwards.

Now the hard part..

My unmanaged C++ library generates status messages as it runs and I'd like to be able to display these from the calling C# application.  My current thinking goes like this:

I'd like the unmanaged C++ library code to call a function in my C# code that I pass to the managed wrapper as I create it.  I've found a few tutorials on Code Project but the syntax seem to be out of date.

If anyone has some sample code or could point me in the direction of a good tutorial that would be great.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: How exactly does the syntax seem out of date? Can you give us an example?

Comment: Are you looking to do a callback since you say the c++ is a library why does your library need to call your code.

Comment: Are you using managed C++ (old syntax) or C++/CLI (new syntax)?  If you are not sure, do you use `^` as the pointer for managed objects in your C++ or `*`

Comment: Hi Lou, I'm using the new C++/CLI syntax.  The old style syntax I mentioned came from a turorial here http://www.codeproject.com/KB/mcpp/unmanaged_to_managed.aspx.

Comment: Hi rerun, the intention of the callback is to pass status messages back to the calling appliction.  They take the form of strings that I'd like to display in the C# GUI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a .NET delegate to a C++/CLI function that takes a pointer to a function with "matching" arguments.

Caveats

1. The pointer-to-function must be STDCALL calling conventions
2. If the delegate is a member of an object, this pointer to function will not count as a reference to keep the object alive.  You have to maintain a reference to the object during the time that the callback is held

Since you think your examples are out of date, I am going to assume you are using the new syntax of C++/CLI.  Here is a CodeProject with an example of how to do that

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/mcpp/FuncPtrDelegate.aspx

Comment: Hi Lou, thanks for that it defiantly got me started.  For anyone else whose interested I also just found this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/367eeye0(v=vs.80).aspx which helped make sense of things.

Comment: Pay careful attention to point #2 in my answer or your object might get GC'd before you call back into it.  The existence of the pointer-to-function does not hold a reference.